# Diferencias entre grano fino y grano grueso

Tags: java, hilos, multitasking

He leído numerosas documentaciones acerca de las diferencias entre el paralelismo de grano fino y el de grano grueso, pero no llego a entenderlo muy bien, dejo aquí un ejemplo de lo que he visto:

> **"Una aplicación muestra un paralelismo de grano fino si sus subtareas deben comunicase muchas veces por segundo, se considera paralelismo de grano grueso si no se comunican muchas veces por segundo(...)" Fuente: Wikipedia.**

A la hora de implementar por ejemplo una multiplicación Matriz x Vector, ¿en qué difieren una implementación de grano fino y otra de grano grueso?

Yo he realizado ya una solución de grano fino creando un hilo **por cada fila** de la matriz para luego operar con ella pero, si ahora quiero hacer una solución de grano grueso, ¿cómo tendría que implementarlo?

Lo que he pensado ha sido, en mi caso, usar la ecuación de *Subramanian* con Coef. de bloqueo 0 por ejemplo para sacar el número de hilos necesarios y luego dividir la dimensión que tenga la matriz entre el número de hilos para lanzar un hilo por **bloque** y no por filas como en la de grano fino.

A ver si consigo de una vez enterarme de cómo funciona cada paralelismo.

Comment: Poco ganarás con crear demasiados hilos de ejecución. Es un tema en el que no ya recetas pre-fabricadas, pues la respuesta a cada problema específico depende de las condiciones de dicho problema. Una de ellas es que, como yo lo veo, por regla general, en tareas de uso intensivo del procesador, dónde no hay tiempos de espera de recursos externos, como discos, redes u otros procesos, se gana más con unos pocos hilos (por ejemplo crear tantos hilos como núcleos tiene el procesador), pues los cambios de contexto también tienen un costo y empeoran el desempeño si hay muchos hilos.

Comment: Entendido, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tipo de paralelismo que implementas en un sistema es una decisión de arquitectura.

Imagínate por ejemplo un sistema que calcula reflejos, luces y sombras para un objeto 3D y luego los aplica a la vista básica. Asumiendo que los tres componentes se pueden calcular independiente de los otros y hay 3 o más nucleos disponibles para cálculos paralelos, tiene sentido de correr 3 hilos, uno para reflejos, uno para luces y uno para sombras, aplicándolos a la vista básica luego que terminan los hilos paralelos. Eso sería un uso de grano grueso.

```
grano grueso

                            +--(reflejos)-+
                           /               \ 
                          /                 \ 
---(main)---(crear hilos)+-----(luces)-------+(resultado)---(juntar capas)
                          \                 /
                           \               /
                            +--(sombras)--+
```

En otro ejemplo quieres implementar un sistema distribuida como un servidor de chat por TCP. Como los mensajes entrantes son eventos que ocurren fuera del control del flujo de trabajo del servidor y por razones técnicas hay que correr los *InputStream* y *OutputStream* en hilos distintos. La mejor función del sistema se consigue si la distribución de mensajes funciona en tareas lo más cortos que posible. Se podría usar un paradigma como un *Scheduler* para difusión de mensajes en hilos trabajadores reciclables. Eso sería un uso de hilo fino.

```
grano fino

-(in){1,n}----(msg1)--+-(ent1)-(msg2)-(msg3)--+---+--
                 \
                +-+(hilo_1)+--------------------
               /            \
              +----(hilo_2)---------------------
             /                \
------(pool)+---+--(hilo_3)------------+--+------
             \   \              \     /    \
              +++--(hilo_4)----+-------+--------
              /  \ \          /   \ /   \   \
-(out)----(msg1)--+-(ent1)-(msg2)-(msg3)--+---+--
```

Answer (score 2):

A lo que entiendo con grano fino es cuando los hilos operan de forma que uno espera la ejecución del otro.

Ejemplo el segundo hilo deberá esperar a que el primer hilo termine o libere la zona crítica, por lo que un mismo recurso es compartido, ya sea el total de las sumas, principalmente utilizando funciones wait(), notify(), join(), etc.

Como en el ejemplo de la siguiente página.

http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Multiplicar_matrices_con_hilos

Y el caso de grano grueso es cuando el hilo actua de forma independiente a lo que es el resultado final, sin compartir gran cantidad de información entre los hilos.

Por lo que a grandes rasgos, grano fino es principalmente para cosas de poco trabajo para prevenir un bloqueo, y grano grueso es la acumulación de granos finos que permitan funcionar de forma independiente.

[image: Open Source SOA]

Me basé en esta respuesta.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766845/coarse-grained-vs-fine-grained

Comment: He entendido tu explicación perfectamente, si alguien pudiera confirmar lo que has dicho, sería de gran ayuda y daría tu respuesta como definitiva, a ver si alguien que vea este tema puede hacerlo. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

La granularidad de los procesos paralelos es relativa. En términos generales, se puede decir que una baja granularidad es a nivel de tareas y una alta granularidad es a nivel de datos y se fundamenta en una estructura simple y repetitiva. Por ejemplo, problemas de cálculo numérico, como el método de los elementos finitos (MEF en castellano o FEM en inglés) es un método numérico general para la aproximación de soluciones de ecuaciones diferenciales parciales muy complejas utilizado en diversos problemas de ingeniería y física, y que se puede resolver con una granularidad muy fina, limitada por la disponibilidad de hardware. Cuando la situación no es tan estructurada, se puede dividir una tarea en subtemas, con una granularidad baja. Por ejemplo, un sistema transaccional puede atender clientes de manera paralela o concurrente.